# Find the explicit solution for the following differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2-4$$

Separating the variables, I get

$$\frac{dx}{x^2-4} = dt$$

Let us write it in partial form

$$\frac{dx}{(x-2)(x+2)} = dt$$

$$\frac{dx}{4(x-2)} - \frac{dx}{4(x+2)} = dt $$

$$ \frac{dx}{(x-2)} - \frac{dx}{(x+2)} = 4dt $$

$$ \ln{|x-2|} - \ln{|x+2|} + C_1 = 4t + C_2 $$

Let $C_2 - C_1 = C$

$$ \ln{|\frac{x-2}{x+2}|} = 4t + C $$

$$e^{\ln{|\frac{x-2}{x+2}|}} = e^{4t+C}$$

$$e^{\ln{|\frac{x-2}{x+2}|}} = e^{4t}e^C$$

Let $e^C = C$ Since it is a constant

$$\frac{x-2}{x+2} = Ce^{4t}$$

Let $x(0) = x_0$

$$\frac{x_0-2}{x_0+2} = C$$

Substituting for C

$$\frac{x-2}{x+2} = \frac{(x_0-2)e^{4t}}{x_0+2}$$

I am rather stuck in here. The solutions manual to this question gives:

$$x(t) =\frac{2[x_0 + 2 + (x_0 - 2)]e^{4t}}{x_0 + 2 - (x_0 - 2)}$$

The solutions manual does not elaborate on how it came to the solution above. How do I approach the problem? Any hints?

Source: Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems: Computing and Modeling (5th Edition) 
by C. Henry Edwards (Author), David E. Penney (Author), David T. Calvis (Author)

Question 5 Chapter 2.2

NOTE: $x(0)$ is not given at all so this is not a mistake. Hence, we simply do $x(0) = x_0$.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a particular point $(x,y)$ that the curve satisfies given to you? Otherwise I don't see how you can find the explicit solution.

Comment: Nothing is given on the initial value condition. Hence, the weird looking solution.

Comment: Personally I've never seen a question without an IVT. Are there any others in the book without one that you were able to find the explicit equation of?

Comment: @SkeletonBow Not having an initial value is fine in my book.  Just denote it $x_0$ and assign it a value if you ever do get a value for it.

Comment: I suppose that, in the denominator of the last expression, $e^{4t}$ is missing.

Comment: @SimpleArt I see, but what I meant that I don't know if you can find an explicit solution without one. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SkeletonBow Sometimes you might not be able to find the explicit solution without that information, but you can here.

Comment: The first question on this chapter is finding the explicit solution for $\frac{dx}{dt} = x-4$ Which, using the same steps above, we could find $x = e^t(x_0-4)+4$

Comment: An explicit solution depends on the initial value of the equation. It is related to the value of x(0), hence we should be able to find a 'formula' for x(t) given x(0). Doesn't matter whether x(0) is a variable or not. We are trying to find this 'formula'.

Comment: @TheValars I see, thank you for explaining that to me! I thought by "explicit" it meant a definite one without variables.

Comment: will componendo-dividendo work?

Comment: Once we separate $x(t)$ alone given $x(0) = x_0$, we should be able to replace $x_0$ with any number we want, and we have the explicit solution, in exact numbers, for that particular initial value.

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal Hmm that might actually work. The solution is indeed in the correct format.

Comment: @TheValars but the thing that concerns me is that how can one ignore the $e^4t$. That thing in exponential will make the right hand side slightly different from the answer given. Are you sure you copied it right?

Comment: Yes, that was what concerns me too. Yes, this is exactly the solution. I expect the solution to have the $e^{4t}$ though since it's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your steps are correct.

From your last equation,
$$
\frac{x-2}{x+2} = \frac{(x_0-2)e^{4t}}{x_0+2}
$$
clear denominators
$$
(x + 2 ) (x_0-2)e^{4t} = (x-2)(x_0+2)
$$
sort for $x$-terms
$$
x ((x_0+2)- (x_0-2)e^{4t}) = 2  (x_0-2)e^{4t} +2(x_0+2)
$$
and divide for the correct answer

$$
x(t) =\frac{2[x_0 + 2 + (x_0 - 2)e^{4t}]}{x_0 + 2 - (x_0 - 2)e^{4t}}
$$

You can verify it by plugging it into the DEQ  $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2-4$ which perfectly holds true.

Hence, indeed the book has **two** printing errors: the $e^{4t}$ has to show up in the denominator,  and the  $e^{4t}$ in the numerator has to be inside the bracket.

Anyway, it's always a good idea to verify the solution (your own one, or the book's one) with a symbolic computer program like Mathematica, Matlab, Wolfram Alpha (free) or SAGE (free). In a publication (see [here](http://arachnoid.com/sage/)) on computational maths I was shocked to read the following:

"exhaustive testing eventually revealed that the problem actually lay with the textbooks. In some published tables the error rates exceeded 25%."

So there is good reason for healthy scepticism even in textbooks.

Comment: I think the question was how to get from OP's answer to the explicit form, not whether the given solution was correct.

Comment: Mind showing me how you derive the answer?

Comment: Please see edit in the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help. The solution makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If $$ \dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}, $$

then

$$ \dfrac{a+b}{a-b}=\dfrac{c+d}{c-d}. $$

This is *Componendo& Dividendo Rule* of elementary algebra which if applied to your last but one equation gives the last equation of the manual.